# Bad button bar icons images in ckeditor textarea

Tags: ckeditor

I'm integrating ckeditor instances inside alpaca forms. I've a strange behavior sometimes : Instead of [image]

I have this :
[image]

This issue is not systematic and seems to be browser dependent, as I hardly have it in Safari, while it is more frequent on chrome.

Any clue about this ?

Answer (score 1):

That happens usually when the browser uses a cached version of the toolbar icons.

Clear the cache of Chrome and verify with Firefox and IE.